# Does Celery use result backend in combination of chain and group?

Tags: python, celery

In my python project i want to use celery for creation pipeline of tasks: some tasks will be grouped and this group is part of chain. Schema of pipeline:

```
 task_chain = chain(
    group(
        chain(taks1.s(uid=uid, index=i), task2.s(uid=uid, index=i)) for i in
        range(len(collection))
    ),
    task3.s(uid=uid),
    task4.s(uid=uid),
    reduce_job_results_from_pages.s(job_uid=job_uid),
    push_metrics.s(job_uid=job_uid))
```

Should i use result backend in this case or only broker is enough?
I don't understand what technology celery use to sync results of tasks and pass result of previous task or group of tasks to next one in chain.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is somewhat provided in the [Important Notes](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#important-notes) section on the Canvas page:

> Tasks used within a chord must not ignore their results. In practice this means that you must enable a result_backend in order to use chords. Additionally, if task_ignore_result is set to True in your configuration, be sure that the individual tasks to be used within the chord are defined with ignore_result=False. This applies to both Task subclasses and decorated tasks.

You may wonder that you could get away without it since you do not use Chord. - I believe Celery will transform any Chain with a Group in it into a Chord.